# Inconsistent behavior when removing minimize button from Windows Terminal

Tags: c, winapi, windows-terminal

I am using the Windows API to disable the minimize button from the current console window (Windows Terminal).

Here is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <windows.h>


bool disableMinimize ( HWND hwnd )
{
    // use styles
    DWORD style = GetWindowLong( hwnd, GWL_STYLE );
    DWORD exStyle = GetWindowLong( hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE );
    // set the window styles
    style &= ~WS_MINIMIZEBOX;
    exStyle &= ~WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
    // set the window styles
    SetWindowLong( hwnd, GWL_STYLE, style );
    SetWindowLong( hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, exStyle );
    // return
    return true;
}

int main() {
    disableMinimize( GetConsoleWindow() );
}
```

What is expected is that the minimize (-) button on the window is greyed out or inaccessible, but this doesn't seem to be working when I am running on Windows Terminal.

The theory I have is that Windows Terminal is forcing WS_MINIMIZEBOX to be true, otherwise I am stumped.

What am I missing?

Comment: The terminal/console window is not your window to mess with. GetConsoleWindow is deprecated.

Comment: Which window should I be using then? How do I get the handle for that?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this at all. This isn't your window.

Comment: Is there another way I can remove the minimize/maximize button from this?

Comment: Why are you trying to change the behaviour of Windows Terminal?

Comment: I'm just wanting to get access to the window of the terminal, and disable the minimize box as I would like the option to.

Answer (score 1):

The Terminal draws its own minimize button (in XAML), and doesn't rely on the win32 styling at all for this. If you'd like to remove the minimize button from the Terminal, you should probably file a feature request on the [Terminal repo](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/).

*<here be dragons>*

Theoretically, you can get the win32 titlebar back by disabling [`showTabsInTitlebar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/appearance#hide-the-title-bar). Know, however, that `GetConsoleWindow` isn't going to get you the handle of the actual Terminal HWND - it will only get you a hidden HWND associated with that tab. I cannot stress this highly enough - don't mess with `GetConsoleWindow`. It's a bad API, and it really does NOT play nice with the Terminal.

</>